# 301 redirect throws an error saying the page being redirected does not exist

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i want to redirect from a page at /roofing/bellevue/index.php to /bellevue-roofing.php  I entered the following:

```
Redirect 301 /roofing/bellevue/index.php http://www.emeraldstate.com/bellevue-roofing.php
```

into .htaccess in the root directory.

The result of entering www.emeraldstate.com/roofing/bellevue/index.php is:

The requested URL /roofing/bellevue/index.php was not found on this server.
I have checked and rechecked various sources on formatting Redirects and everything seems correct.  Can anyone provide a little guidance?

Comment: You used `/roofing/index.php`, which is why it isn't working...

Comment: not sure I understand what you are saying.  In case you meant that .php is not supported, I changed it to /roofing/index.htm.  Now even the home page gets redirected which makes even less sense to me.

Comment: Huh? I'm saying that you want to redirect from `/roofing/bellevue/index.php`, but you are asking it to redirect from `/roofing/index.php`. Those URIs are not the same, so why would you expect it to work?

Comment: I see what you are saying.  my mistake.  that was a typo.  I indeed tried doing a redirect from /roofing/bellevue/index.php to /bellevue-roofing.php and it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The correct implementation is to avoid specifying the domain name as part of the redirect. Whilst this will more than likely make no difference to your setup, I'm mentioning it anyway.

You'll be better off using `RedirectMatch` or `mod_rewrite` (which I prefer):

```bsh
RedirectMatch 301 ^/roofing/bellevue/index.php$ /bellevue-roofing.php
```

Or use `mod_rewrite` (make sure that the extension is enabled, which it generally is):

```bsh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/roofing/bellevue/index.php$ /bellevue-roofing.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank you for the response but the response on the server to using the mod-rewrite commands is the same:

The requested URL /roofing/bellevue/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Is that another typo? Did you try to request `/roofing/bellevue/index.php`?

Comment: this time it was not a typo.  i copied your mod_rewrite rules and put them in .htaccess and the response above is what I got back.  So yes I did request /roofing/bellevue/index.php

Comment: Did you try with `RedirectMatch`? There is a chance that your `mod_rewrite` is not enabled.

Comment: yes I did.  I am now on the phone with GoDaddy.  I found a service on GoDaddy web site to set up redirects and it throws the same error.  I'll let you know what I find out.